# Hide IP from flash objects

Tags: ip, flash, ip-address, flash-player

Running a flash plugin will make it able to retrieve my real IP address even if I'm using a proxy.
Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: By running Flash you give it access to that basic system info.  If you don't want it to have that simple access, then your only probable choice is to not use Flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is absolutely impossible to execute something client side, and hide basic host configuration information from it. the only alternative would be to proxy the execution itself (for instance execute it on a virtual host that you are connected to via remote desktop or another screen sharing protocol).